# UUID as PK good idea?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

at the moment i an looking at a table with 210 million records. The primary key is a 36 char alphanumeric key (uuid).

Would it be better for storing to use a sequential number as PK and the UUID as normal column?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more compact, but the data would be harder to move between systems while maintaining data integrity.

So if you have to move the data, use UUID's. Otherwise, I see no benefit and some disadvantages.